# Recommend retagging "Desktop-Dungeons-Paid" to "Desktop-Dungeons"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Now that Desktop Dungeons has released on Steam and is likely to see a much wider user base, I recommend retagging [desktop-dungeons-paid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-paid) to simply be [desktop-dungeons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons). The other tag is [desktop-dungeons-free](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-free), so either way it should be clear which is which. A good tag wiki should clear up any possible remaining confusion.

Anyone coming to ask or search for questions about the game is likely to simply type in [desktop-dungeons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons). We also don't add [paid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paid) to any other game that requires money to play but has a free version or demo, so our current tagging is a bit inconsistent.

Comment: No, we should again go with desktop-dungeons-2013 and desktop-dungeon-200something

Comment: @badp Isn't it the same game? The paid version changed to the one they have now, but the free version is still the same.

Comment: @lyr is that any different from the Stanley parable?

Comment: @badp Dunno never played the mod or the new one. But it is now impossible to get the old paid version of desktop dungeons? Only the new and the free version. My guess is it is still possible to get the Stanley parable mod?

Comment: @badp [tag:desktop-dungeons-paid] is the same game that just released. It's been a constantly evolving beta for 2+ years that just finally left beta stage. Paying just gave you access to the beta, rather than the alpha, which is what the free version was. I could maybe see renaming [tag:desktop-dungeons-free] to have a year instead, but I'm not sure which year you'd pick that would be appropriate for [tag:Desktop-dungeons-paid], since the "paid" version has existed since the same year as the free version. It's just had an awful lot of updates in the meantime.

Comment: @Sterno The new version has been released this year: 2013. The old version was released in 2010. Picking years is quite simple here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I propose

- [desktop-dungeons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons) ← [desktop-dungeons-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-2013), [desktop-dungeons-paid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-paid)
- [desktop-dungeons-2010](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-2010)  ← [desktop-dungeons-free](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-dungeons-free)

Comment: Assuming the leftmost is the tag to use, and the ones to the right are synonyms, I'm on board with this proposal.